# How to get winston log file from inside a container and make it persitent

Tags: docker, docker-compose, winston

I have the following in my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

server:
   container_name: backend
   build: ./backend
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  - ./backend/logs:/logs

.
.
```

Now, when I do docker-compose up, logs (using winston for logging) are sent to the log file inside the container but do not reflect on the log file on host. If I manually manipulate the file on the host, it reflects on the log file in the container.

How do I sync the log files and update the host log file in real time

Comment: If you use `winston.transports.Console()` as your log target and not a file, logs will show up in the `docker logs` output (or a foreground `docker-compose up`); that might be more manageable long-term.

Comment: What about a database? I have tried doing so with mongodb but I keep having errors

Comment: can you help me that where is the location of log files when using docker?
I can not see Winston logs when using docker

Comment: They are created inside docker container. You have to user a volume to access it.